# How to understand projection matrix in the view of linear transform?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

The projection matrix of projecting $\mathbb R^n$ onto vector $v$ is $\frac{v v^T}{v^T v}$, which is a $n\times n$ square matrix. For simplify the question, I only talk about projection onto *one* vector, which is a 'line'.

**Proof**

If project $w$ onto $v$, $w$ can be written as $w=p + e$

1. $p$ is in the column space of $v$. So, $p$ can be written as $p=vx$, $x$ is a scalar.
2. $e$ is perpendicular to $v$. So, $v^T e=0$

So,
$$
\begin{aligned}
&v^T e=v^T(w-p)=v^T(w-vx)=0 \\
\implies & v^Tw=v^Tvx \\
\implies & x= \frac{v^Tw}{v^Tv} \\
\implies & p=vx=\frac{vv^Tw}{v^Tv}=\frac{vv^T}{v^Tv}w \\
\implies & \text{projection matrix is } \frac{vv^T}{v^Tv}
\end{aligned}
$$

**My Confusion**

But in the view of linear transform, projection is a transform from $\mathbb R^n$ onto a 'line'. The dimension of $\mathbb R^n$ is $n$ and dimension of a 'line' is 1, so I have two questions:

1. I think the matrix of projection transform should be $1\times n$, so, is $n\times n$ square matrix $\frac{v v^T}{v^T v}$ a right matrix for the projection transform of $\mathbb R^n$ onto vector $v$?
2. If $n\times n$ square matrix $\frac{v v^T}{v^T v}$ is a right matrix for projection transform, how to understand? I think it means a transform from n-dimension standard basis $\begin{bmatrix}1&0\dots0\\0&1\dots0\\ \vdots & \vdots \ddots \vdots \\ 0&0\dots1\end{bmatrix}$ to n-dimension standard basis. But I don't think n-dimension standard basis is a basis of a 'line', even if every element of 'line' may be written in a unique combination of n-dimension standard basis. Because there are at least $n-1$ vectors of n-dimension standard basis, that cannot in the 'line' subspace.

Answer (score 1):

$\frac{vv^T}{v^Tv}$ is not a matrix !! It is a number which is equal to $1$ whenever $v \neq 0$.

---

To find the projection of a vector $x$ onto the span of $a$. You need to find $\lambda \neq 0$ such that

$$ \langle \lambda a, x- \lambda a\rangle = 0 $$

(make a drawing to see why !) Solving for $\lambda$ gives

$$ \lambda\langle a, x\rangle - \lambda^2\langle a,a\rangle = 0 \iff \lambda = \frac{\langle a, x\rangle}{\langle a, a\rangle} $$

So our projection is the following map

$$P : x \mapsto \frac{\langle a, x\rangle}{\langle a, a\rangle} \times  a $$

---

To answer your specific questions :

1. The fact that the dimension of the image of the projection is the line. Does not require the matrix to be $1 \times n$.
2. As I've already said the matrix of the linear transformation is not $\frac{vv^T}{v^Tv}$.  The fact that the matrix is $n \times n$ means that the image of the projection is contained in $\mathbb R^n$. This is normal because the "line" is a subspace of $\mathbb R^n$.